# Need some suggestions on how to improve these command string generator functions

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ interface for a line based protocol. The commands are simple, they are structured like this:

```
<cmd> <args>\n
```

Some commands have a fixed number of arguments, some have variable ones. I am using ostringstream to assemble the line. I wrote two base classes to cover the commands with and without variable arguments:

```
class format_command
{
public:
    explicit format_command(std::string const &p_cmd_name)
    {
        m_sstream << p_cmd_name;
    }

    std::string get_string() const;

protected:
    std::ostringstream m_sstream;
};


class format_command_with_args
    : public format_command
{
public:
    explicit format_command_with_args(std::string const &p_cmd_name)
    {
        m_sstream << p_cmd_name;
    }

    template < typename T >
    format_command_with_args& operator << (T const &p_value)
    {
        m_sstream << " " << p_value;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Individual command line generators are then derived as needed. Let's take two example commands, `foo` and `bar`. `foo` takes a fixed number of arguments, `bar` variable ones.

```
class format_foo
    : public format_command
{
public:
    explicit format_foo(std::string const &p_string, int const p_number)
        : format_command("foo")
    {
        m_sstream << " " << p_string << " " << p_number;
    }
};


class format_bar
    : public format_command_with_args
{
public:
    explicit format_bar(float const p_decimal, char const p_char)
        : format_command("bar")
    {
        m_sstream << " " << p_decimal << " " << p_char;
    }
};
```

And then I have functions that create instances of these classes.

```
namespace command
{


format_foo foo(std::string const &p_string, int const p_number)
{
    return format_foo(p_string, p_number);
}


format_bar bar(float const p_decimal, char const p_char)
{
    return format_foo(p_decimal, p_char);
}


}
```

I can then do this:

```
std::string command_str = command::foo("hello", 11).get_string();
std::string command_str = (command::bar(1.2f, 'x') << "extra-arg" << "another-arg").get_string();
```

I added this indirection through the command:: functions because some commands are like this:

```
somecmd <arg1> <arg2> [<arg3> [<varargs>]]
```

meaning that they have variable arguments only if a specific argument is present. So, if the third argument isn't present, I want to make sure that the user cannot add extra variable arguments with the stream operator. In such cases, I can then do this:

```
class format_somecmd
    : public format_command
{
public:
    explicit format_somecmd(std::string const &p_arg1, std::string const &p_arg2)
        : format_somecmd("bar")
    {
        m_sstream << " " << p_arg1 << " " << p_arg2;
    }
};
class format_somecmd_with_args
    : public format_command_with_args
{
public:
    explicit format_somecmd_with_args(std::string const &p_arg1, std::string const &p_arg2, std::string const &p_arg3)
        : format_somecmd("bar")
    {
        m_sstream << " " << p_arg1 << " " << p_arg2 << " " << p_arg3;
    }
};

namespace command
{

format_somecmd somecmd(std::string const &p_arg1, std::string const &p_arg2)
{
    return format_somecmd(p_arg1, p_arg2);
}

format_somecmd_with_args somecmd(std::string const &p_arg1, std::string const &p_arg2, std::string const &p_arg3)
{
    return format_somecmd_with_args(p_arg1, p_arg2, p_arg3);
}
```

This way, I can do this:

```
std::string command_str = command::somecmd("hello", "world").get_string();
std::string command_str = (command::somecmd("hello", "world", "test") << "extra-arg" << "another-arg").get_string();
```

and this fails at compile time (which is intentional since it would be an invalid command):

```
std::string command_str = (command::somecmd("hello", "world") << "extra-arg" << "another-arg").get_string();
```

This works well so far. The part that bothers me though is the `.get_string()`. I have considered using `operator std::string()`, but this seems like a can of worms.

Any suggestions on how to improve it, particularly with regards to `get_string()` ?

Comment: This is not for command-line switches, but for a line based protocol.